# Why doesn't the Salary Calculator have a way for me to list Linux as one of my "skills"?

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

Is it not statically significant? I assume the sub set of tags that are available were chosen because they are the most telling of a person's salary ...

Comment: The calculator is based on the results of a user survey - if not enough people responded with that option, it will not be there.

Comment: TBH, "platforms" is kinda inconsistent in general. Looks like a Sesame Street "One of these things is not like the other" segment. AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, Windows... and Wordpress?

Comment: @Oded is the data for the survey available somewhere?

Comment: How does one be skilled in "Linux"?

Comment: @TylerH the same way one is skilled in "Windows".

Comment: @John Same question applies: how is one skilled in "Windows"? The point is that such a statement is so broad and vague that it is useless. What part of Windows are you skilled in? Installing it? Using it? Who cares about that? Are you skilled with PowerShell or Active Directory and Group Policy? etc. be specific about what you're skilled in. "Skilled in Linux" tells me you don't actually know anything about Linux beyond just using the OS, which isn't really a skill.

Comment: It's just like millennials who put "Microsoft Office" as a skill on their résumé; while slightly more specific than "Windows", it's an indicator of BS. Sure, they know how to use Microsoft Word, PowerPoint, and Excel a little, but if I put some VBA down in front of them or ask them to make me a pivot table, or probably even *open* Microsoft Access and ask them to make me a new table and a form, they would probably be completely lost. I make the same determination when I see "Skilled in [insert OS here]". They just put that stuff on there because people hiring them are old and slow w/ MS office

Comment: @TylerH First, I don't disagree that it's ambiguous. I just wanted to know why it wasn't included in the salary calculator for which Oded provided an answer. Second, perhaps instead of using the word "skill" I should have chosen the word "technology" as is used on the calculator. This alone seems to have caused great confusion. Lastly my estimated salary is higher if I omit Windows rather than include it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that Linux is a skill in the same way that "word processing" is a skill.  That is to say, simply saying that you know "Linux" tells you *even less* about what the candidate actually means.

You surely know that there are many flavors of Linux and that there are many ways to approach Linux.  It'd be more useful to pinpoint what type of Linux interaction matters for a salary, like system administration, or desktop support (yes, there are Linux desktop users out there who wouldn't mind a little corporate support - I'm one of them).

But simply saying that you have Linux as a skill isn't valuable since it's  arguably ambiguous.

I likely list this as something on my resume, but I make sure to disambiguate what I mean - I've had experience administering Debian and RPM-based Linux servers, as well as being familiar with Bash, and having used desktop Linux for about twelve years now.  The salary calculator needs to show that to us instead of the blanket term.

Comment: Maybe we just need to add [nunchuck skills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsiiIa6bs9I) and call it good.

Comment: I think the same argument, to a lesser extent, could be made of Windows.

Comment: @John:  Oh, absolutely.  I don't disagree there either.  I'm willing to bet that for reasons described by Oded that Windows appears, though.